# HAProxy dynamic server address based off of variable

Tags: haproxy, sni

I want to dynamically route to a server by making use of a request variable ssl_fc_sni. Is it possible to configure haproxy server statement to use a variable for address and/or port?
Example

`backend citest3bk_spice_default
  server compute1  %[ssl_fc_sni] ssl verify required crt server.pem ca-file ca.pem force-tlsv12 weight 0`
 
Currently, I get an error
`parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:157] : 'server compute1' : invalid address: '%[ssl_fc_sni]' in '%[ssl_fc_sni]'`

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like that won't work. I don't think that's a good idea either as the end users can then give the IP address of *any* web server which would be used as the backend. That sounds like a huge security issue to me.

Why not statically configure a backend for each webserver you want to access directly and then based on a cookie or custom URL route the traffic to that backend containing only the single server?

Comment: I have given a single server as an example. I have potentially 100s of server statements to handle. I was looking for neat way to handle this instead of filling the config with an exhaustive server backend list
As for the security issue, I can trust the sni as all my connections in my case are TLS connections with client certificates - so both sides of a connection are verified.